# Заполнить массив нулями и единицами

Tags: python

Заполнить массив нулями и единицами, при этом данные значения чередуются, начиная с нуля. Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 50 # длина массива
a = [i%2 for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 2):

**способ 1:**

```
arr = [i % 2 for i in range(n)]
```

**способ 2:**

```
arr = ([0, 1] * ((n + 1) // 2))[:n]
```

чуть менее оптимально, но более коротко:

```
arr = ([0, 1] * n)[:n]
```

**способ 3:**

изврат на способе 1:

```
arr = list(map(lambda i: i % 2, range(n)))
```

**способ 4:**

изврат на способе 2:

```
arr = list(str(bin(int("0x" + "A" * n, 16)))[3:3 + n])
```

**способ 5:**

```
generate = lambda n, s = False: [int(s)] + generate(n - 1, not s) if n > 0 else []
arr = generate(n)
```

Comment: Для полноты ответа надо ещё на генераторе)

Comment: сейчас сейчас - еще думаю :)

Comment: А что-нибудь с yield?)

Comment: ну вы, сударь,
 и извращенец, конечно.

Answer (score 1):

А ещё проще

```
(0,1) * 10
```

если массив это list,

```
[0,1]*10
```

а на 19 элементов можно обрезать

```
([0,1]*10)[:19]
```

Comment: это для 20 элементов - а для 19 :)